# How to get the search results code number in GitHub with GitHub API?

Tags: github, github-api, github-api-v4

I have the following search term

> navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition

which return 271,769 code results, how I can return the code results number by using github API

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [GitHub Search API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/search) to search code. More precisely, the following endpoint:

```
[GET] /search/code
```

Since you are only interested in the total number, you can set the `per_page` parameter to 1 in order to make the the result smaller. The number of results is returned in the response as `total_count`:

```
{
  "total_count": 435249,
  "incomplete_results": false,
  "items": [
    ...
  ]
}
```

Example using the GitHub command line tool:

```
gh api -X GET search/code -f q='navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition' -f per_page='1'
```